# Tensorflow Quantization - Failed to parse the model: pybind11::init(): factory function returned nullptr

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, quantization

I'm working on a TensorFlow model to be deployed on an embedded system. For this purpose, I need to quantize the model to int8.
The model is composed of three distinct models:

1. CNN as a feature extractor
2. TCN for temporal prediction
3. FC/Dense as last classfier.

I implemented the TCN starting from [this post](https://medium.com/the-artificial-impostor/notes-understanding-tensorflow-part-3-7f6633fcc7c7) with some modifications. In essence, the TCN is just a set of 1D convolutions (with some 0-padding) plus an add operation.

```py
## Define TCN newer
tcn_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=tf.keras.backend.int_shape(glue)[1:])
# first causal conv for channel adaptation
k=1; d=1; padding = (k - 1) * d
# tcn_input_p = tf.pad(tcn_input, tf.constant([(0,0), (1,0), (0,0)]) * padding)
temp_block_input = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32,k, padding='valid', data_format='channels_last', name='adapt_conv')(tcn_input)

# TEMPORAL BLOCK 1
k=2; d=1; padding = (k - 1) * d
# temp_block_input_p = tf.pad(temp_block_input, tf.constant([(0,0), (1,0), (0,0)]) * padding)
temp_block_input_p = tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding1D((padding, 0))(temp_block_input)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32,k, padding='valid', data_format='channels_last', dilation_rate=d, activation='relu', name='conv1')(temp_block_input_p)
temp_block_input = tf.keras.layers.Add()([temp_block_input, x])

# TEMPORAL BLOCK 2
k=2; d=2; padding = (k - 1) * d
# temp_block_input_p = tf.pad(temp_block_input, tf.constant([(0,0), (1,0), (0,0)]) * padding)
temp_block_input_p = tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding1D((padding, 0))(temp_block_input)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32,k, padding='valid', data_format='channels_last', dilation_rate=d, activation='relu', name='conv2')(temp_block_input_p)
temp_block_input = tf.keras.layers.Add()([temp_block_input, x])

# TEMPORAL BLOCK 3
k=2; d=4; padding = (k - 1) * d
# temp_block_input_p = tf.pad(temp_block_input, tf.constant([(0,0), (1,0), (0,0)]) * padding)
temp_block_input_p = tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding1D((padding, 0))(temp_block_input)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32,k, padding='valid', data_format='channels_last', dilation_rate=d, activation='relu', name='conv3')(temp_block_input_p)
x = tf.keras.layers.Add()([temp_block_input, x])

tcn = tf.keras.Model(tcn_input, x, name='tcn')

tcn.summary()
```

I try to quantize the TCN with the following code (which works for other models, eg the CNN)

```py
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(tcn)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.int8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8

def representative_dataset(): # generate the inputs
    for sample in x_train:
        yield [cnn(i) for i in sample]

converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset
quant_model = converter.convert()

with open(os.path.join('models','tcn_q.bin'), 'wb') as f:
    f.write(quant_model)
```

And I get the error below. I also unsuccessfully tried the following:

- Use the format saved_model and then `tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(path)`
- use `tf.Add` and `tf.pad` instead of the keras API
- Remove the Add operation to make the model sequential

```
Failed to parse the model: pybind11::init(): factory function returned nullptr.
```

I could not find a solution so far, but I believe it should be possible to quantize this network, as the operations I use are basic and should be supported.
I can also use some workaround if anything comes to mind, but I'd like to understand which part is creating the issue.

As a side node, I also inspected the network with [netron.app](https://netron.app), and it seems the 1D convolutions are transformed into a 2D convolution using some additional Reshape, ExpandDims and BatchToSpace layers. I'm not sure if this might be an issue though.

[image: TCN without the add layers]

Comment: Which TF version are you using? Could you try your conversion script with TF 2.4 or tf-nightly? tf.Add is deprecated one so I would recommend sticking with the keras layers.

Comment: Ok I'll stick to keras. I'm already using TF 2.4.0.

Comment: FYI, tf.add is okay to use. Sorry for making the confusion.

Comment: I could reproduce your issue on my side. TF 2.4.x has a problem with your case. However, I verified the tf-nightly version fixes your issue already. Please check out this colab. https://colab.research.google.com/gist/abattery/d837c042a4fe5459ff740739011cc29a/tcn-conversion-colab-tf-nightly.ipynb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [@JaesungChung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11843861/jae-sung-chung), the problem seems to be solved using tf-nightly (I tested on 2.5.0-dev20210325).

It's possible to obtain the same effect in 2.4.0 using a workaround and transforming the Conv1D into Conv2D with a width of 1 and using a flat kernel (1, kernel_size).